# Index error while transposing matrix in script

Tags: python, list, matrix

I have  program that transposes a square matrix:

```
matrix = [[1, 2, 4], [3, 6, 9], [6, 8, 2]]
matrix _trans = []

for i in range (len (matrix)):
     for j in range (len (matrix)):
         matrix_trans [j] [i] = matrix [i] [j]
```

Error:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Why is this error produced here?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `matrix_trans` is just and empty list, that is why you can not access any indx, build a copy of `matrix` instead:

```
matrix = [[1, 2, 4], [3, 6, 9], [6, 8, 2]]
matrix_trans = [x[:] for x in matrix]
```

Answer (score 1):

That happens because of `matrix_trans[j][i]`, in the first iteration both `j` and `i` will be zero and `matrix_trans` is an empty list, so `matrix_trans[0]` would raise an index error, you should have a copy of your first matrix's dimensions in the strat, like this:

```
from copy import deepcopy
matrix = [[1, 2, 4], [3, 6, 9], [6, 8, 2]]
matrix_trans = deepcopy(matrix)

for i in range(len(matrix)):
     for j in range(len(matrix)):
         matrix_trans[j][i] = matrix[i][j]
```

result:

```
In [41]: matrix_trans
Out[41]: [[1, 3, 6], [2, 6, 8], [4, 9, 2]]

In [42]: matrix
Out[42]: [[1, 2, 4], [3, 6, 9], [6, 8, 2]]
```

for more information about `copy` module read [Docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html)

Also, note that for this action you can use Python `zip`. like this:

```
list(zip(*matrix))
```